# Simple sum if expression

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements, data.table

These are my sample data:

```
dt <- data.table(id=c("a","a","a","a","b","b"), monthsinarrears=c(0,1,0,0,1,0), date=c(2013,2014,2015,2016,2014,2015))
```

The table looks like this:

```
> dt
   id monthsinarrears date
1:  a               0 2013
2:  a               1 2014
3:  a               0 2015
4:  a               0 2016
5:  b               1 2014
6:  b               0 2015
```

Now I want to create an additional column called "EverinArrears" which will be assigned with "1" if the id was ever in arrears (historically) and "0" if it wasn't. Thus the output I want to obtain is:

```
   id monthsinarrears date EverinArrears
1:  a               0 2013             0
2:  a               1 2014             1
3:  a               0 2015             1
4:  a               0 2016             1
5:  b               1 2014             1
6:  b               0 2015             1
```

Note that loan id `a` was not historically in Arrears in 2013 (this happened in 2014) so that's why EverinArrears gets a 0 zero as well in 2013.

Comment: your result does not match the data you gave!

Comment: why? I simply want to add this additional column EverinArrears based on the first table I provided and the conditions I provided.

Comment: look at your initial dt, and what you have written ... this completely differs, even if your question is understandable overall ;)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel you are right! I did not noticed that, but I see that the question has been updated correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the following (thanks to @Roland for the hint to avoid numbers > 1) :

```
dt[, EverinArrears := as.integer(as.logical(cumsum(monthsinarrears))), by=id]
```

Output:

```
#   id monthsinarrears date EA
#1:  a               0 2013  0
#2:  a               1 2014  1
#3:  a               0 2015  1
#4:  a               0 2016  1
#5:  b               1 2014  1
#6:  b               0 2015  1
```

***Note:*** if you prefer a shorter code, you can also do

```
dt[, EverinArrears := +(!!(cumsum(monthsinarrears))), by=id]
```

although is not as "good practice" as `as.integer(as.logical(...))`

***As mentioned by @Jaap, you can also do:***

```
dt[, EverinArrears := +(cumsum(monthsinarrears) > 0), by = id]
```

or, for better practice:

```
dt[, EverinArrears := as.integer(cumsum(monthsinarrears) > 0), by = id]
```

***As suggested by @Arun in the comment, another, simpler, way:***

```
dt[, EverinArrears := cummax(monthsinarrears), by = id]
```

Comment: Just wrap in `as.logical`.

Comment: another possibility: `dt[, EverinArrears := +(cumsum(monthsinarrears) > 0), by = id]`

Comment: `cummax(monthsinarrears)` or `cummax(monthsinarrears > 0L)` would also fit here..

Comment: @Arun, it's indeed a better suited function (I must say I didn't know this function). Thank you very much, I've added the option

Answer (score 5):

Here's a slight variation on the others' answers:

```
dt[, newcol := cummax(monthsinarrears > 0), by=id]
```

By using `cummax` instead of `cumsum`, we might save on some computations.

---

And here's a way of comparing against the position of the first entry with positive months in arrears:

```
dt[, newcol := {
  z = which(monthsinarrears > 0)
  if (!length(z)) rep(0L,.N)
  else            replace(rep(1L,.N), 1:.N < z[1], 0L)
}, by=id]
```

Not sure if that might be any more efficient; it certainly depends on the data to some extent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ave`:

```
dt$EverinArrears = as.integer(!!ave(dt$monthsinarrears, dt$id, FUN=cumsum))
```

Or the good approach with data.table:

```
dt[, EverinArrears := +(!!cumsum(monthsinarrears)), id][]
```

Comment: Don't use `ave` with a data.table. That's unnecessarily slow.

Comment: I posted `ave` solution with since the `!!cumsum()+0L` did not work with data.table first :)

Comment: Using `as.logical` and `as.integer` is better practice (clearer code and marginally faster).

Comment: Don’t use “clever” syntax hacks such as `!!`. They are entirely unnecessary and obscure what’s actually meant. There’s no harm in being explicit here: `x != 0` is what you should want to write. But actually not, since the result is converted back to an integer anyway. Incidentally, the same goes for `+as.logical(x)`: it’s likewise a syntax hack. The actual logic here is encapsulated instead by `sign(cumsum(x))`.

Comment: I will delete this answer anyway since copying seems to be a must on SO :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph If you want to be transparent, do `ifelse( x > 0, 1, 0)`. `sign` is no great substitute (since its use suggests that the number might be negative; as does `x != 0` instead of `x > 0`). And while `+x` is a hack, it's not like `?as.integer` does a better job of telling you how the coercion from logicals to integers works. Maybe the right course is to tell the OP "logicals are what you want -- don't bother converting to 0/1."

Comment: @Frank I’m also not a great fan of `as.integer` for the reason you mentioned. I’d always be explicit; alas, `ifelse(…)` is *much* slower, so some concession has to be made.

Answer (score 2):

Using package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(EverinArrears = +as.logical(cumsum(monthsinarrears))) %>% 
  data.table

   id monthsinarrears date EverinArrears
1:  a               0 2013             0
2:  a               1 2014             1
3:  a               0 2015             1
4:  a               0 2016             1
5:  b               1 2014             1
6:  b               0 2015             1
```